# Protecting files in desktop Mac .app

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I'm mainly write iPhone apps but am familiar with some desktop Mac authoring.  I need to create a Cocoa app that will include several wav sound files (included in bundle).  I don't want a user viewing package contents of the .app file and then extracting all of the sound files from it.  Is there a way to protect those files?

Comment: I suggest making them m4a files with AAC compression instead of plain old WAV files. Your app will be much smaller that way.

Comment: Although off topic, great suggestion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some possibilities, depending on the effort you feel like putting in:

1. Encrypt the files
2. Change the filename and extension to make it less obvios that they're sound files
3. Embed the sounds inside an executable file, as a custom Mach-O
   section
4. Strip any headers from the files, and store just the raw
   samples
5. Write a program to convert the audio data to C array
   declarations, and compile into the app
6. Just don't worry about it. Nobody's
   going to "steal" your sounds, and if
   they did, so what?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt them. That's about it.

Comment: No, because there are probably a million different ways of encrypting files out there, many of which cannot be used in many countries.